# Regular expression in Java for splitting a String

Tags: java, regex

What is the regular expression in Java for splitting a String like: 
`[space]0[space]` (space followed by zero followed by space)?

e.g.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

splits as:

```
123456789101112131415
```

and

```
12345
```

Comment: Is this an example, or an actual list of integers? It seems very simple without a regex anyway.

Answer (score 5):

```
String[] split = string.split(" 0 ");
```

Unless you meant "any whitespace" when you said space. Or "a sequence of one or more space characters".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having some extra spaces: `\b0\b`.

If you do want to remove spaces, this should work for the start and end zeros as well: `\s?\b0\b\s?`

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the spec does not match the example.

Comment: Careful with Java character class shortcuts: they’re wacky.

Comment: @tchrist - I know. *Obviously*, I meant the OP should use the alternative regex library you're writing `:)` (OK, J/K, but I hope it's all right when dealing with regular spaces and regular zeros)

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
string.split("\\s0\\s");
```